# Hidden Markov Model - Observations

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, hidden-markov-models

I'm struggling to understand the statistic relation referring the observations of an HMM. That's clear for me: [Output Independence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FKi0.png)

My problem is how this equation can be derived: [probability of an observation given the state sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIeox.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have an HMM with hidden state sequence $Q_0,Q_1,\dotsc, Q_T$ and observations $O_0,O_1,\dotsc,O_T$ that respect the graph:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Q_0 @>>> Q_1 @>>> \cdots @>>> Q_{\textit{T-1}} @>>> Q_T \\
@VVV @VVV @. @VVV @VVV \\
O_0 @. O_1 @. @. O_{\textit{T-1}} @. O_T
\end{CD}
$$
It follows that the joint distribution of these variables takes the form:
$$
\textstyle p(q_0,q_1,\dotsc,q_T; o_0, o_1, \dotsc, o_T) = p(q_0) \prod_{i=1}^T p(q_i | q_{i-1}) \prod_{i=0}^T p(o_i | q_i)
$$
where:
$$
\textstyle p(q_0,q_1,\dotsc,q_T) = p(q_0) \prod_{i=1}^T p(q_i | q_{i-1}).
$$
We can then calculate the conditional probability of interest as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(o_0, o_1, \dotsc, o_T | q_0,q_1,\dotsc,q_T) &= \frac{p(q_0,q_1,\dotsc,q_T; o_0, o_1, \dotsc, o_T)}{p(q_0,q_1,\dotsc,q_T)} \\
&= \frac{p(q_0) \prod_{i=1}^T p(q_i | q_{i-1}) \prod_{i=0}^T p(o_i | q_i)}{p(q_0) \prod_{i=1}^T p(q_i | q_{i-1})} \\
&= \textstyle \prod_{i=0}^T p(o_i | q_i).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Ok, but what is the thought of setting in ∏Ti=0p(oi|qi) in your first equation? The rest is understandable, thank you. Though the crux is for me the following thought: the probability of p(oi|qi) is directly based on the state i, but you're multiplying them with the joint probability, what's the background of that?

Comment: Ah, I see. That follows from the output independence that you mention in your question. We always have a breakdown like so: p(q,o0,o1,o2,o3) = p(q)p(o0|q)p(o1|q,o0)p(o2|q,o0,o1)p(o3|q,o0,o1,o2), and output independence allows us to simplify the terms, e.g., p(o0|q)=p(o0|q0), and p(o1|q,o0) = p(o1|q1). Repeated application of this principle and output indepedence gives us the first equation.